# Simple table-like visual appearance in Windows Forms (c#)

Tags: c#, tablelayoutpanel

I currently develop an application, which reads a XML file containing some fields, which tell me what kind of controls etc. I want to (dynamically) load. Then it creates those controls and adds them into a TableLayoutPanel.

However since I do not need Columns (I'm pretty sure, that this won't change) and since dynamically removing/adding rows to a TableLayoutPanel is cumbersome, I'd like to know if there is a free or paid alternative to this panel.

Also: it bothers me, that I cannot set the BorderStyle of the whole panel (for some reason BorderStyle is not accessible).

So does anyone know an alternative (for Windows Forms)? In Java I'd probably use a GridBagLayout (which also is quite a bit more straightforward than the TableLayoutPanel), but it seems there's no good alternative to the TableLayoutPanel (or I haven't found any).

Thank you very much in advance. If you need any further information, please do not hesitate to ask.

Comment: Have you considered a [FlowLayoutPanel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.windows.forms.flowlayoutpanel.aspx)?

Comment: Yes, but I need the Panel to display controls one **under** and its (the panels) size may vary, because the window is resizable.

Comment: FlowLayoutPanel seems to work like a charm - I didn't know, that you could set FlowDirection and WrapContents. Together it makes it very easy to add controls back and forth as long as it stays one-column. Thank you. I think I'd mark your answer as the correct one as this is what I'll be using. Would be cool if you posted it separately so I can mark it as the answer to my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you could use a [DataGridView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.aspx). And you can change the border styles and colors. Look at [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ehz9ksfa.aspx).

In addition, here is [another grid control](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5462/C-grid-control) that looks simple enough for your needs.

Comment: Hm I'm not exactly sure if it's smart to use a DataGridView in order to position various controls one under the other, but I will have a look at this and report back.

Comment: @Igor - Check out [this article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/12265/How-to-add-other-controls-to-DataGrid-Part-I). I think it might help you